# get 2 texts from this line

Tags: text-processing, cut

Get 2 texts from this line:

```
[23/08/2019 09:30:00 351] [DEBUG] [Hilo:Thread-17905] [Clase:co.com.colombiamovil.activator.db.PoolFacade: getSiebelDirectConnection (81)] [Conexi???n establecida  7682 siebelDB: TMAC70580369126846, duraci???n: 90]
```

Output:

```
23/08/2019 09:30:00 | duraci???n: 90
```

or

```
23/08/2019 09:30:00 | 90
```

With this I take the duration:

```
grep "duraci???n: " ussdGw.log | cut -d" " -f16 | tr -d "]"
```

but I can't get the date out

Help me

Answer (score 1):

You could just use `awk` for this:

```
$ awk 'gsub(/[][]/,""){print $1,$2,"|",$NF}' file
23/08/2019 09:30:00 | 90
```

The `gsub(/[][]/,"")` will replace all occurrences of either `[` or `]` (that's a character class: `[ ]` consisting of two characters `]` and `[`, so becomes `[ ][ ]`) on the current line and then, if that was successfull, you print the 1st field (the date), the second field (the time) and the last (NF) field, the duration.

Comment: tks    served me with    grep "duraci???n: " ussdGw.log | cut -d" " -f1,2,15,16 | tr -d "]"      very easy

Comment: This is an elegant solution. I need to learn more awk!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to parse a logfile with lots of lines?
Making use of [substring-manipulation](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html):

`$ cat get2texts.sh`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
logfile="$1"
IFS=']'
while read -r one two three four five junk; do
  one="${one#[}"
  one="${one% *}"
  five="${five/*,/ | }"
  echo "$one $five"
done < "$logfile" \
| tr -s ' ' ' '
```

**Result:**

```
$ get2texts.sh testfile
23/08/2019 09:30:00 | duraci???n: 90
```

Comment: [It's usually a bad idea to do this sort of text parsing in the shell.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/22222).

Answer (score 0):

If you set FS sensibly, you might get away with e.g.:

```
awk '{ print $2, $3, "| " $(NF-1) }' FS='[] []+' infile
```

Output:

```
23/08/2019 09:30:00 | 90
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the date and duration in lines containing `duraci???n:` with `sed`:

```
$ sed -n 's/^\[\([^ ]* [^ ]*\).*\(duraci???n:.*\)\]$/\1 | \2/p' logfile
23/08/2019 09:30:00 | duraci???n: 90
```

or

```
$ sed -n 's/^\[\([^ ]* [^ ]*\).*duraci???n: \(.*\)\]$/\1 | \2/p' logfile
23/08/2019 09:30:00 | 90
```

Explanation of the first command:

- `sed -n` be silent (only matched parts are printed with the `p` flag)
- `'s/` substitute
- `^\[` match `[` at the start of the line
- `\(` start first group
- `[^ ]* [^ ]*` match date and time (any no space characters followed by space followed by any no space characters)
- `\)` end first group
- `.*` match any characters
- `\(` start second group
- `duraci???n:.*` match `duraci???n:.*` followed by any characters
- `\)` end second group
- `\]$` match `]` at the end of the line
- `/\1 | \2/` replace with first group, `|` and the second group
- `p'` print matches

Answer (score -1):

```
awk '{print $1,$2,$NF}' filename| sed "s/\[//g"|sed "s/\]//g"| awk '{$NF=" | "$NF;print $0}'
```

output

```
23/08/2019 09:30:00  | 90
```

Comment: reason for downvote